# WPF application icon when sending notification is pixelated in windows 10

Tags: wpf, notification-icons

I have an application that shows a balloon tip/notification. When I upgraded to windows 10, the application icon is pixelated.

Here's what it looks like
http://screencast.com/t/A5lb2RW1jf

Here's how I show my notification:

```
NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = balloonTipTitle;
notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = ballonTipText;
notifyIcon.Text = text;
notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(500);
```

By the way, I'm using a multiple layer icon. I have a 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 and 256x256

Am I missing something? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Where are you setting the icon of the `NotifyIcon`?

Comment: What do you mean settings? That's all there is to it.